# mpicc hangs when called from makefile; runs fine as single command

Tags: compilation, makefile, mpi, icc

i'm trying to compile WRF (doubt that's relevant) and am having a problem where mpicc will hang when run w/ the compile script.  icc and mpif90 have no issues.  the compile script is executed w/ #!/bin/csh -f

just to be verbose, here's an example.  i run the script and get here

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/jason/wrf/wrf3.5/external/RSL_LITE'
mpicc  -DMPI2_SUPPORT -DMPI2_THREAD_SUPPORT -DFSEEKO64_OK  -w -O3  -DDM_PARALLEL -DMAX_HISTORY=25 -DNMM_CORE=0  -c rsl_bcast.c
```

and hang.  so then i run that line by itself

```
jason@server:~/wrf/wrf3.5$ cd /home/jason/wrf/wrf3.5/external/RSL_LITE
jason@server:wrf3.5/external/RSL_LITE$ mpicc  -DMPI2_SUPPORT -DMPI2_THREAD_SUPPORT -DFSEEKO64_OK  -w -O3  -DDM_PARALLEL -DMAX_HISTORY=25 -DNMM_CORE=0  -c rsl_bcast.c
jason@server:wrf3.5/external/RSL_LITE$
```

compiles instantly.  starting the compile script again does the exact same thing but on the next file.  i have no idea what to do, and this is basically impossible to google for.

Comment: Could it be different compilers? Type `which mpicc` in the terminal and put this command into the script before `mpicc` invocation. Also, add `-v` option to the mpicc to increase verbosity.

Comment: negative, same mpicc.

Comment: Does `-v` option show anything before it hangs?

Comment: If the compiler, which gets called by `mpicc`, requires a license (e.g. a floating network license), it might hang due to the license server being unavailable at that moment or the license path environment variable not being properly set in `csh` scripts. When you compile a file by hand, it generates an object `.o` file and hence the makefile skips that source file and continues with the next source file.

Answer (score 0):

Does the command work if you start it like

```
env -i $SHELL -c 'cd /home/jason/wrf/wrf3.5/external/RSL_LITE && mpicc -DMPI2_SUPPORT -DMPI2_THREAD_SUPPORT -DFSEEKO64_OK -w -O3 -DDM_PARALLEL -DMAX_HISTORY=25 -DNMM_CORE=0 -c rsl_bcast.c
```

? It could be that a missing environment variable is the culprit.

Also, what are those extra spaces in the command? Can you try running `uniname -bcp Makefile` to see if there are any non-`[ \t\n]` characters in there which could be messing with the command line?

Answer (score 0):

for archival purposes, the solution was to add "-cc=icc".